# Overflow-x hidden no body

Tags: html, css, rolamento

Adicionei Overflow-x: hidden no body mas não está funcionando.

overflow hidden desativa o scroll, ou só esconde a barra?

```css
html, body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-x: hidden;
  
}
/* tentei das duas formas */
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Apenas esconde a barra. Qual o resultado esperado e qual o resultado obtido?

Comment: com esse css que adicionei ele só está ocultando a barra, quando o resultado desejado é bloquear a rolagem horizontal

Comment: E o que implica em sua página a barra ocultar ao invés de bloquear apenas ? Você pode usar o `overflow-x:auto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para prevenir scroll, o melhor é não deixar os elementos excederem o tamanho máximo do elemento pai. Do contrário, o único jeito é com um pouco de Javascript:

```
function wheel(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if ( e.wheelDeltaX !== 0 ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};

function disable_scroll() {
    if ( window.addEventListener ) {
        window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
};

disable_scroll();
```

Veja funcionando: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mg1x63v/)